# C# How can I change the grouping in my program? (Beginner)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-code-model

So I'm doing a program where I have a group of salesmen(five), who have names, IDs, their living district and the number of articles sold. And at the end based on how many numbers sold, they will be grouped into 4 rankings. The thing is when I get the results, the rankings/groupings appear at the bottom, for example:

I type in these FIVE sellers and they appear just like this, I can type in what I want they're not set:

name: Jon

ID: 657577

District: West

Articles: 200

Then a new seller with the exact same thing underneath
and at the very end, after every FIVE sellers have been written, it calculates how many go into each group like this for example

2 sellers have reached level 1: < 50 articles

1 seller has reached level 4: > 200 articles

The problem is, I want the levels to appear immediately AFTER the number of sales in each group, so I want the grouping to occur directly.
Let's say Jon and FILIP sold under 50, then both of them will appear in level 1.

Like this

name: Jon

ID: 657577

District: East

Articles: 33

name: Filip

ID: 63636

District: West

Articles: 20

2 Sellers have reached level 1: <50 articles

and then let's say I do one more seller named Anna who has sold 200, then she would immediate after be put into group 4. Instead of the grouping appearing at the very end.

SO how can I then change the order of when their groupings appear in the program? Instead of the bottom, directly underneath depending on how many they have sold?

I thought this was the part of the program where you alter their positional placement when they're written out in the console

```
Console.WriteLine("\nName:\tId: \tDistrict: \tArticles:");

Console.WriteLine("\n"+seller[i].name+"\t"+seller[i].id+"\t" + seller[i].district+"\t"+seller[i].products);
```

But it seems wrong. I also have these lines

```
Console.WriteLine("\n{0}{1}\n", number, level);
                    
file.WriteLine("\n{0}{1}\n", number, level);
                   
 number = 0;
                   
 level = k.level;
```

But I'm not totally sure of what I should alter to fix this, but it seems simple.

Comment: Consider doing all the calculations separately, and then only start outputting (eg. calling `Console.WriteLine()`) once you have all the requisite data ready - this will force you to think of the "business logic layer" (the rankings) as entirely separate from the "presentation layer" (as it should be)

Comment: @ Mathias R. Jessen I think I know what you're saying, I'll see what I can do